# Make enums defined inside structs in C++ have global scope

Tags: c++, c, enums, scope, compatibility

The following code will compile as C, but not as C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct somestruct {
    int id;
    enum {
        STATE1 = 0,
        STATE2,
        STATE3,
        STATE4,
    } state;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static struct somestruct s;

    if (s.state == STATE1) {
        printf("state1\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In C++, I would have to use `somestruct::STATE1` (because the enum declaration is restricted to the struct/class?).
The project I'm working on is to be written in C, but currently we use some C++ libraries (Arduino), so we're compiling our c-code with a C++ compiler. So is there any way to make the above code compile in C++?

Comment: re-write it(pull the enum out of struct)? If you cant rewrite it, you can still use it with the correct C++ way

Comment: Nice question (Tried extern "C", which is not helpful)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. In fact, you must already know it, because you've explicitly mentioned it in your question. Use `somestruct::STATE1` instead of `STATE1`!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could code it in a form that is compatible with both languages, such as:

```
typedef enum 
{
    STATE1 = 0,
    STATE2,
    STATE3,
    STATE4,
} eState ;

struct somestruct 
{
    int id ;
    eState state ;
};
```

Alternatively if you really cannot change the struct and enum definition then the following is portable (if ugly), and requires that you change every *reference* to the enum rather then the single *definition* (i.e. it has little merit IMO):

```
#if defined __cplusplus
    #define SOMESTRUCT(e) somestruct:: e
#else
    #define SOMESTRUCT(e) e
#endif
```

Then:

```
...
    if (s.state == SOMESTRUCT(STATE1)) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `using` statement to bring the identifier into the calling scope:

```
struct somestruct {
    int id;
    enum {
        STATE1 = 0,
        STATE2,
        STATE3,
        STATE4,
    } state;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
using somestruct::STATE1; // <-- here
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, yes, exactly as you said: refer to it as `somestruct::STATE1`.

I don't see how you're going to be able to make this portable across both languages, but then again I don't see why you need to. Write `somestruct::STATE1` in the C++ code, and `STATE1` in the C code. Use macros if you *really* need to flip between them without duplicating code.

Don't forget to fix your broken expression `s->state`; `s` is not a pointer.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a c macro definition

```
#define STATE1 somestruct::STATE1
```

That Should Allow To Go STATE1
I Would Recommend Against it since you are using a c++ compiler so you might as well make use of the c++ features that it gives you and just put somestruct::STATE1.